# Skrill(Moneybookers) cancel recurring payment

Tags: php, payment-gateway, recurring

I would like to know how to detect if the skrill(moneybookers) recurring payment is cancelled by the customer? And also, is there a way to cancel the recurring payment using their API?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "direct notifications" and you will receive notifications for every important change, like when a customer cancels.

And yes you can cancel recurring payments using their API.

All developer documentation here:
https://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=m_shoppingcart